# Structure for top hit objects

Tags: c++, data-structures, priority-queue, unordered-map

I want to have a `hit` parameter for `object`s that are received, showing its frequency. and being able to have the most frequent, top `hit`, `object`s. 
`Unordered_map` fits the first part, having `object` as the key and `hit` as the value.

```
unordered_map<object,int>
```

It enables searching fast for `object` and incrementing its `hit`. But how about sorting? `priority_queue` enables having the top hit object. But how about incrementing the object's hit?

Comment: Are you referring to a specific language?

Comment: Yes, the code is in c++.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at [splay tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) that keeps objects in a way that most recent and most frequnetly accessed objects are closer to the top. This relies on several euristicts and thus will give you an approximation of the perfect solution.

For an exact solution it is better to implement your own [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) and implement the operation icrement priority. In theory the same is used for backing for `priority_queue`, but there is no cahnge priority operation, while it can be done without affecting the complexity of the data structure's operations.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't figure out what to do. binary heap is good to have the objects sorted, but to increment I need to search key. How to implement fast search? Isn't there any way to use implemented structures in C++/boost?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved it by keeping track of sorted list of objects by their hit number as I insert the objects. So there is always the list of the most N top hits. There are 3,000,000 objects and I want to have the top 20.

Here are the structures I used:
`key_hit` to keep track of hits (by key, a string, I mean the object):

```
unordered_map<string, int> key_hit;
```

two arrays : `hits[N]`, `keys[N]` which contains the top hits and their corresponding key (object).

```
idx,    hits,   keys
 0,     212,    x
 1,     200,    y
 ...
 N,     12,     z
```

and another map `key_idx` to keep the key and its corresponding index:

```
unordered_map<string,int> key_idx;
```

Algorithm (without details):

- `key` is input.
- search the `key` in `key_hit`, find its hit and increment (this is fast enough).
- if `hit<hits[N]`, ignore it.
- else, `idx=key_idx[key]`, (if not found, add it to structures and delete the existing one. it too long to write all details)
- `H=h[idx]++`
- check whether it is greater than the above entry, `h[idx-1]<H`. if yes, swap idx and idx-1 in `key_idx`,`hits`,`keys`.

I tried to make it fast. but I don't know how far it's fast.